# Ruby .count operation truncates input file

Tags: ruby, file-io

I want to read a file in and show how large it is. .count is acting like .count! and changing the size of my input file buffer. so now logfile.each doesn't iterate. What's going on?

```
logfile = open(input_fspec) 
puts "logfile size: #{logfile.count} lines"
```

Answer (score 3):

`count` will read all the lines from the input in order to do the counting. If you want to read the lines again (e.g. using `readline` or `each`) then you will need to call `logfile.rewind` to move back to the start of the file.

In fact, what `count` is actually returning is the number of lines that have not been read yet. For example, if you had already read through the file and called `count` afterwards then it would return 0.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this instead before you even open it:

```
File.size("input_fspec")
```

Comment: This would return the size of the file in bytes not the number of lines in the file.

Comment: True.  I didn't notice where you said you wanted the number of lines in the file.